# Forgotten to answer question

Tags: exams, grading

Seeing [Forgot to answer exam question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/100343/forgot-to-answer-exam-question) and thinking back to my exam that I wrote a day ago, I think it **might be me** who forgot!

I recall the last few exam questions but not answering them!

Should I speak to the professor to see if anything can be done or should I leave it be?

(all the details match me... A+ so far and also submitted a draft earlier...)

Comment: Maybe you should be proactive and post the correct answer to the question(s) you forgot to answer here. Who knows, the professor might be impressed enough with your brilliance they’ll accept the late submission.

Comment: The professor has to mark what was submitted. They may possibly decide to make an executive decision to remove the last question as many students did not do it then that is their choice.

Comment: @DanRomik this could be potentially bad for both professor and student. By making the question and answer public, they risk exposing themselves and maybe violate confidentiality of course material. We can't know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want an A+ then of course you could ask. Maybe he will consider the previous draft, maybe he won't; but it never hurts to ask.

You should be aware, though, that he is not obligated to give you points for it; it is completely your fault for forgetting to answer the questions. Therefore, don't demand points but ask nicely if there is any chance to consider the draft, you will have better chances this way.

Comment: How does a professor distinguish between a student ‘forgetting’ vs not having time to get to those questions?